# Failure in CV to account for upvotes

Tags: support, status-bydesign, community-wiki

I received two upvotes and an answer check on a response to an OPs question but the CV system failed to register them. Here is a link to this:

[Text to read to prepare for course in advanced data analysis (second-level data analysis graduate course)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/213328/text-to-read-to-prepare-for-course-in-advanced-data-analysis-second-level-data/213330#213330)

This seems like a bug.

Why would this be happening? Is it too late to get the credit?

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts.

Comment: @whuber  Ah! Didn't realize it had been tagged as "community wiki."

Comment: That's understandable, because we don't have the ability to make a thread CW at the outset: a moderator has to come across the question and convert it to CW.  More often than not, that occurs after one or more replies have been offered (CW questions tend to be "softball" questions and quickly collect answers).  Reputation is accrued by votes applied before CW status is applied and is not reversed afterwards: you get to keep any ill-gotten gains! :-)  This issue of CW's effect on reputation has been [somewhat controversial](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2953).